# Clean way to bind enums dynamically to Select dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have drop-down lists with options that can vary based on who is using the application. The thought is to create enums for the drop-down options and attach it to the `<select>` tag by doing the following:

```
public ListOfEnums? PropertyValue { get; set; }

public enum ListOfEnums
{
    OptionA,
    OptionB
}

public enum ListOfEnumsAlternate
{
    OptionY,
    OptionZ
}

<select asp-for="PropertyValue" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ListOfEnums>()"></select>
```

This works great if the drop-down options are static. However, in our application the options can change based on how a previous field was answered or based on other property values. So we might need to show `ListOfEnumsAlternate` in some cases.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this and still use enums or would a different option (client side with jQuery?) be better?

Comment: This is what javascript was designed for. For simple stuff that is few/far between, some simple jquery will probably suffice. For anything more complicated you might want to look into client side rendering using ReactJS or Angular or things can quickly get out of control.

Comment: As soon as you say something like "options can change based on how a previous field was answered", you're talking about client-side interaction, which then requires AJAX to fetch new information.

Comment: `PropertyValue` is `ListOfEnums` so it will only bind to a vale which is `OptionA` or `OptionB`. You need a separate property in your view model to bind to `ListOfEnumsAlternate`

Answer (score 0):

As the page is generated by the server, your only way to do it without client-side code would be to call the server after the previous field is filled. This is a heavy behavior and doesn't seem needed in your case.

The best way to handle this is to have two dropdownlists in your page (one with `ListOfEnums` and the other with `ListOfEnumsAlternate`).

Then, you display only one of them using javascript code when the previous field is filled.

Comment: If I have two `<select>` elements on my view bound to same `PropertyValue` won't that cause issues when the form is submitted?

Comment: @RyanBuening, Yes it will (although you could disable one), but it also means your 2nd `<select>` will not have any client side validation (no `data-val-*` attributes are generated)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, so it doesn't appear that this would be a good option in my case. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanBuening, Certainly not if you were to bind both the the same property (and if you selected from the 2nd one, the value of `PropertyValue` will be null, because values `OptionY` and `OptionZ` cannot be converted to `ListOfEnums`)